# Gathering rows to 1 row and adding column

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

Hello I am currently learning programming and I am working on a project of php and mysql, but I have a problem.

What I am doing is I have a table called `marks` and every time people add a mark to a student, they add a column to the table, the table looks like this:

```
|------------------|
|  subject | marks |
|------------------|
|   math   |  16   |
|  english |  18   | 
|  history |  15   | 
|  math    |  14   |  
|  english |  20   |  
|------------------|
```

But I want to change it like this when I treat it:

```
|-------------------------|
|   math   |  16   |  14  |
|  english |  18   |  20  |
|  history |  15   |      |
|-------------------------|
```

**How can I do this with mysql's query, or php if needed?**

Well my final goal is to make html table with this but I already know how to do it.

I am sorry if it looked simple, but I am really a beginner at databases and programming and I apologize if the title confuses you guys.

Comment: A [Cross-Tab Query](http://evolt.org/node/26896/) is perfect for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
SELECT subject, GROUP_CONCAT(marks ORDER BY marks) marks
  FROM table
 GROUP BY subject
 ORDER BY subject
```

It will give you two columns, one with a comma-separated list of subjects.

```
english 18, 20
history 15
math    14, 16
```